# Is there endianness issue reading string data from NSInputStream

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, endianness, external-accessory

I am reading binary data from NSInputStream that is written from a third party source (e.g. hardware) through external accessory framework and convert it to string.  Is there endianness issue that I should be concerned about, i.e. should I ask the hardware provider what endianness they are using when they send their string in?

Comment: I think so. NSInputStream provides you with raw data whether it be little or big endian so you must take care of it. Good question by the way, +1.

Comment: If we are using UTF8 or ASCII encoding, there should be no endianness issue, no?

Comment: In case of ASCII, no. In case of UTF8, there may be.

Comment: UTF-8 does not have endian issues.

Answer (score 0):

As people have said, probably not if you're using ASCII or UTF8. Most processors nowadays, even in dedicated devices, use little endian.

On an unrelated note, if you're doing networking via external accessories, you might have to watch for network and host byte orders.